# Error on Sitecore Sidekick Content Migrator

Tags: sitecore-sidekick

I recently installed Sitecore Sidekick and I am now trying to pull content from Production environment to my Dev environment. It is a Sitecore 7.2 installation instance. when I try to pull content from production, I am getting the following error. I did some initial troubleshooting and found that there is no such physical path in the my website folder as mentioned in the error below. Anything I am missing?

[image]

Comment: How did you install it? Did you install it on both dev + production? What steps lead you to seeing this error and in what environment?

Comment: The error is in dev environment where I have installed it. It is not installed in Production or any other environments yet. Do I need to do that for a 2-way communication purpose?

Comment: Yes you will need it installed in both environments. Also ensure that you have installed correctly and have the relevant config files under App_Config/Include (e.g. zSCS.config etc)

Comment: Great! I will do that. Is there a Sitecore package I can install this module in other environments or do I copy over files/configs/dlls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned above by Kasaku you need to install the Sidekick module in all environments in order to be able to connect to the service from dev.

You can do this by either:

1. Installing the Marketplace module in each environment: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/S/Sitecore_Sidekick.aspx
2. Install Sidekick via NuGet and deploying the following files to each environment:

> Install Sidekick via NuGet
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/SitecoreSidekickCore/

```
Install-Package SitecoreSidekickCore
```

Ensure any updates to these config files are included in your deployment:

- zSCS.config
- zSCS.Aduitlog.config
- zSCS.ContentMigrator.config
- zSCS.Editingcontext.config

Comment: No problem, Glad you got it sorted. I should probably add that the nuget package install should be done on your local dev environment and then deployed to you staging > prod sites afterwards.